# Spring-MVC PathVariable matching regular expression not starting with word

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I want to match all requests with a PathVariable which are not start with 'api'. I test following RequestMapping. spring could match request but could not get value for PathVariable. How I solve this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name:(?!api).+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getNotApi(@PathVariable String name, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
}
```

I get following message for some request like `localhost:8080/resource`.

`Error 500 Missing URI template variable &apos;name&apos; for method parameter of type String`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name:^(?!api).+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are building on Java pre 8 version, it may be because of missing name. Try `@PathVariable("name") String name`. Keep `@PathVariable` value same as your mapping parameter name.